# How do I implement conditional rendering in a functional React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render

I want to implement conditional rendering in a functional React component. I don't know how to do this in a function.

I need the corresponding imported component to be rendered depending on the state.

I wrote this logic using the ternary operator and everything works, but this code is terrible and unreadable.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import Header from "./header/header";
import Footer from "./footer/footer";

// One of these components will be rendered between Header and Footer ↓
// Name of the component in the state (activeItem)

import Landing from "./landing/landing";
import BookingManagement from "./bookingManagement/BookingManagement";
import BookingTickets from "./bookingTickets/bookingTickets";
import EnterProfile from "./enterProfile/enterProfile";
import PersonalArea from "./personalArea/personalArea";
import Register from "./register/register";
import SearchResults from "./searchResults/searchResults";
import ChoosePlace from "./choosePlace/choosePlace";

function App() {
  const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = useState("landing");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(activeItem);
  });

  return (
    <>
      <Header changeMain={setActiveItem} />
      {activeItem == "landing" ? <Landing changeMain={setActiveItem} /> : <></>}

      {activeItem == "bookingManagement" ? <BookingManagement /> : <></>}
      {activeItem == "bookingTickets" ? <BookingTickets /> : <></>}
      {activeItem == "enterProfile" ? <EnterProfile /> : <></>}
      {activeItem == "personalArea" ? <PersonalArea /> : <></>}
      {activeItem == "register" ? <Register /> : <></>}
      {activeItem == "searchResults" ? <SearchResults /> : <></>}

      {activeItem == "choosePlace" ? <ChoosePlace /> : <></>}

      <Footer changeMain={setActiveItem} />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I definitely need to implement this in the functional component, because I use hooks.

Comment: Why not a map of strings to components?

Comment: Looks like you might be looking for [React Router](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an object which wraps all your components and then use the correct component by using activeItem as the key:

```
    import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

    import Header from './header/header';
    import Footer from './footer/footer';

    import Landing from './landing/landing';
    import BookingManagement from './bookingManagement/BookingManagement';
    import BookingTickets from './bookingTickets/bookingTickets';
    import EnterProfile from './enterProfile/enterProfile';
    import PersonalArea from './personalArea/personalArea';
    import Register from './register/register';
    import SearchResults from './searchResults/searchResults';
    import ChoosePlace from './choosePlace/choosePlace';

    const components = { Landing, BookingManagement, BookingTickets, EnterProfile, PersonalArea, Register, SearchResults, ChoosePlace };

    export default function App() {
      const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = useState("Landing");
      const ActiveItemComponent = components[activeItem];

      return (
        <>
          <Header changeMain={setActiveItem} />
          <ActiveItemComponent />
          <Footer changeMain={setActiveItem} />
        </>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
const ComponentMap = {
  landing: Landing,
  bookingManagement: BookingManagement,
  bookingTickets: BookingTickets,
  enterProfile: EnterProfile,
  personalArea: PersonalArea,
  register: Register,
  searchResults: SearchResults,
  choosePlace: ChoosePlace
};

function App() {
  const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = useState("landing");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(activeItem);
  });

  const ActiveComponent = ComponentMap[activeItem] || React.Fragment;
  const ActiveComponentProps = {};
  if (activeItem === "landing") {
    ActiveComponentProps.changeMain = setActiveItem;
  }
  
  return (
    <>
      <Header changeMain={setActiveItem} />
      <ActiveComponent {...ActiveComponentProps} />
      <Footer changeMain={setActiveItem} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
{(activeItem=='landing' ? (
    <Landing changeMain={setActiveItem}/>
  ) : (
    <></>
  ))}
```

go with

```
{activeItem=='landing' && (
    <Landing changeMain={setActiveItem}/>
)}
```

Comment: While this omits the need of the `:` (else) part of the ternary operator's conditional rendering, it hardly fixes the core issue, which is repeated statements. It's much cleaner to simply have a map of the components and have the `activeItem` be the index to decide which component to render.

Comment: You are right! thank you for the remark 

Answer (score 1):

you can go with react-router implementation. Or if you want to handle the same  in this component you can do similar like below

```
const getComponent = () => {
  if (condition1) {
    return <Component1/>
  } else if (condition2) {
    return <Component2/>
  }
 
  return <DefaultComponent/>
}
```

and inside the render return you can call that function like below

```
return (
  {getComponent()}
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function App() {
    
    const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = useState('landing');
    
    const itemToComponent = [
      landing: {component: Landing},
      bookingManagement: {component: BookingManagement},
      ...
    ]
    const Components = itemToComponent[activeItem].component
    
  return (
    
      {<Components />}
          <Footer changeMain={setActiveItem}/>
       </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].